# Swap class in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class with a virtual property on the server, that I have to replace with another on the mobile app.

The virtual property is defined as

```
public virtual List<object> Collection { get; set; }
```

I have to replace with

```
public override ObservableCollection<object> Collection { get; set; }
```

How can I do this in the most effictive way?

The only way I can think of is to create a method that converts it, but as it is deep inside a collection of a collection..., I want to know if there are better ways

Comment: When you override a method, definition should remain same, you can't change the definition.

Comment: As you say: *replace*. You could use the `new` modifier. `public new ObservableCollection<object> Collection { get; set; }`

Comment: A List<T> is *very* different from an `ObservableCollection`. If you want the second it means that you want to implement *very* different functionality from the original. Changing a single collection isn't going to help. *Why* do you want an ObservableCollection? You don't *need* it to implement MVVM for example, or for change notification.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` and `List`  implement `IList<T>`. Make your property  `IList<object> Collection` instead of `List`

Comment: I want to change it for Change notification, so @PanagiotisKanavos how can I make it for List :o

Comment: @Valentin Is IList serializable?

Comment: @LasseMadsen you'd need ObservableCollection only if you wanted to modify the collection on the fly and trigger an update. Typically though, the data is loaded eg from database, set on a ViewModel property and never modified again. Even when you add/remove items, it's far better to raise the proper events when the method that makes the change finishes. This way you avoid raising 50 updates if you enter 50 different items, *and* you are able to raise notifications for any related properties